# insert constant into field (from select) Postgres

Tags: php, post

This code it work but  put everything ("timestamp8","Last","TradePrice", ,"TradeFlags") into filname column   How can I change it I want to put only "gel" into filname (inthis case $table = gel  )

I try 'gel'  it say Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'gel' (T_STRING) in

Please suggest

```
$sql ='INSERT INTO pong8_maintable ("filname","timestamp8","Last","TradePrice", "TradeFlags"

) 

SELECT
"gel" ,
cast(public.'.$table.'."Timestamp" as timestamp) ,
cast(public.'.$table.'."Last" as numeric)  ,
cast(public.'.$table.'."Trade Flags"as varchar)


FROM Public.'.$table; 


sc_exec_sql($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this it work

```
SELECT
(\''.$table.'\') ,
cast(public.'.$table.'."Timestamp" as timestamp) ,
cast(public.'.$table.'."Last" as numeric)  ,
cast(public.'.$table.'."Trade Price" as numeric)  ,
```

or

```
 SELECT
    (\'gel\') ,
    cast(public.'.$table.'."Timestamp" as timestamp) ,
    cast(public.'.$table.'."Last" as numeric)  ,
    cast(public.'.$table.'."Trade Price" as numeric)  ,
```